# Web Storage types

Tags: performance, session, local-storage, session-variables, pseudocode

After arguing with a few colleages We didnt get an agreement...

My point is the next one: 
Why Should I use Local Storage? I don´t like (as user) that someone stores information in my computer. As longer as I saw, whatever information which I need to store in a Local Storage I can store it in a Session Variable in back side. It´s more confidential and I like to handle this information in our serves.
The only case I would consider to store information in front side will be if that storage could slow down the performance´s server or information related with the UI.

Can you give me any argument? Can you provide me examples where local storage is really necessary, usefull or better?

Thanks mates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,

After asking in different forums and read different articles my conclusions are the next ones:

We must use Web Storage when the information which we want to storage is not confidential. Like web storage is storaged in the local computer, this information could be recover by others and changed or read it.

The original purpouse for this storage methods is for storaging information related with the user and the UI experience of himself.

In my specific case this web storage style is nor recommended. We want to storage the footprint of the changes in DDBB for recovering them after... If someone get access to this footprint (storaged in the local computer) and change it, when we recover them the integrity of DDBB will be affected...

Cheers.